# Dual port NICs for cluster

Tags: networking

What is better in a server environment to get the best performance:

2 x gigabit dual port NIC teamed up

1 x gigabit dual port NIC and 1 x gigabit quad port teamed up

1 x gigabit dual port NIC and 1 x 10GbE dual port NIC teamed up

How would you rate each of the above combinations(teamed up). Please rate them from 0 to 3 (0 being good and 3 being best). and what is the maximum transfer rate I can get from each of the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, if you're looking for transfer rate then a 10GbE adapter will massively outperform a 1GbE adapter. You won't get the full theoretical rate, and you'll spend quite a lot of time playing around with interrupt balancing and other such things to really get the best out of it, but I wouldn't even worry about teaming it with a 1GbE adapter if I were you; that's going to cause you more pain than anything else. Teaming is difficult to get right, and for a 10% theoretical performance gain it's not worth it, you'll get more of a boost from tuning the configuration.

I'd suggest you figure out what you need and how much you'll willing to pay and go from there.  Without knowing more about your application I can't really offer more advice.

Comment: I was considering teaming them in such a way that my 1 gigabit will be on standby in case the 10gbs dies. I understand that the 10gbs will definitely outperform the fist two. Do you think it's an ideal to have 10gbs on master node (that will be working as a management node and saving data) and one of the first two on child nodes? There will be at least 6 child nodes each with 3 6 cores CPU's performing tasks simultaneously for high performance computing.  Which one do you think is better from the first two?

Comment: You need to figure out what your application requires. If you can get away with a 1Gbit adapter just use two teamed up for redundancy, but that's only worth doing if you have redundant switching. If 1Gbps isn't enough and you need redundancy then you'll need dual 10Gbps. There's no point failing onto a setup that won't handle the load, and there's no point having 10 times more capacity than you need. Maybe 1Mbps is enough for your application, if so stick with gigabit.

Comment: What speed can I get with the following:

a) 2 x gigabit dual port NIC teamed up

b) 1 x gigabit dual port NIC and 1 x gigabit quad port teamed up

Comment: If they're good quality PCI-Express NICs and you're aggregating then around 4Gbps and around 6Gbps. If you're teaming for redundancy then 2Gbps and 2Gbps. It'll definitely scale perfectly with the number of adapters/ports (multi-port adapters are just multiple adapters on one board with a PCI-Express switch normally). There will be some overhead due to framing, this is a constant factor and is protocol dependent. There will be some overhead due to interrupts and teaming, this depends on your application.

Comment: I am thinking to go with 2 x gigabit quad port and 1 x gigabit dual port teamed up which will give me 10 ports. Any major disadvantages of that? would you prefer to do the same if you were looking for high transfer rate? thanks for all the help :)

Comment: 10 ports is great, but only if you have a lot of independent connections (at least 250 say), otherwise you're going to struggle to balance the flow across all the ports. At that point you should really just use a single 10Gbps adapter.